# Parse requestURI using GROK Patterns

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I have a field `requestURI` and I am trying to parse it using GROK Patterns and create new fields from it.

```
requestURI=/api/v3/imp/sts/591/metric/WALTF?date=2015-01-11
```

New field name which I am trying create are below:

```
a=sts
b=591
```

Could anyone help me on how to create above fields using GROK?

Comment: Is the value of  *requestURI* going to be in the same format? And how're you getting the value for *requestURI*?

Comment: I tried like this, but it is not working          `ruby {
          code => "
            inputs = event['requestURI'].split('/')
            event[inputs[4]] = b
            event[inputs[3]] = a
          "
        }`

Comment: @Darth_Vader yeah it going to be same format